# Using function to display random numbers, then ifelse statement to allocate days of the week

Tags: javascript, math, if-statement

when user clicks on button, the script should generate a random number and then display the corresponding week day.  The code below is what I have so far, alas it doesn't seem to work.
I have debugged it and apparently myfunction is not defined?!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <body>

    <p>Click the button to display a random number between 1 and 7</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Get Random</button>   

    <p id="task1"></p>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 7 + 1);
        document.getElementById("task1").innerHTML = x;
        }

        if (x===1)
        {
            document.write("today is sunday");
        }
        else if(x===2)
        {
            document.write("today is monday");
        }
        else if(x===3)
        {
            document.write("today is tuesday");
        }
        else if(x===4)
        {
            document.write("today is wednesday");
        }
        else if(x===5)
        {
            document.write("today is thursday");
        }
        else if(x===6)
        {
            document.write("today is friday");
        }
        else if(x===7)
        {
            document.write("today is saturday");
        }

    </script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: I notice the brackets in `var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 7 + 1);` are unbalanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `var x` is **local** variable defined in the `myFunction` body. It is not accessible outside of your function (in all your `if`s).

Also you have redundant opening parenthesis in your `var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7 + 1);` statement.

Corrected version:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7 + 1);
    document.getElementById("task1").innerHTML = x;        

    if (x===1)
    {
        document.write("today is sunday");
    }
    else if(x===2)
    {
        document.write("today is monday");
    }
    else if(x===3)
    {
        document.write("today is tuesday");
    }
    else if(x===4)
    {
        document.write("today is wednesday");
    }
    else if(x===5)
    {
        document.write("today is thursday");
    }
    else if(x===6)
    {
        document.write("today is friday");
    }
    else if(x===7)
    {
        document.write("today is saturday");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the explanation and the fix

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra parenthesis in the `Math.floor` function. Try to run the following and you will see that works.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7 + 1);
    document.getElementById("task1").innerHTML = x;
  
    if (x===1)
    {
        document.write("today is sunday");
    }
    else if(x===2)
    {
        document.write("today is monday");
    }
    else if(x===3)
    {
        document.write("today is tuesday");
    }
    else if(x===4)
    {
        document.write("today is wednesday");
    }
    else if(x===5)
    {
        document.write("today is thursday");
    }
    else if(x===6)
    {
        document.write("today is friday");
    }
    else if(x===7)
    {
        document.write("today is saturday");
    }
}
```

```html
    <p>Click the button to display a random number between 1 and 7</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Get Random</button>   

    <p id="task1"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra parenthesis and the code throws an exception before the function gets rendered.

var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7 + 1);
 document.getElementById("task1").innerHTML = x;

The that you can use the browser console to view exactly what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> It can be much easier and shorter if you use and object *days* for example

```js
//declare the object that holds the days.
    var days=["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];

//declare your function that's triggered when clicking the button.
    function myFunction(){

//declare your variable x that generates random numbers between 0 and 7 ,
// it starts from 0 because the first day "sunday" is days[0] not days[1].
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*7);

//write the result in the p element
    document.getElementById("task1").innerHTML ="today is "+ days[x];
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Here</button>
<p id="task1"></p>
```

Comment: When answering a question with code, you should include some text description about how the code answers the question. Normally, code-only answers are not as useful to others.

Comment: You're right. I will keep it in mind the next times. Thank you